# Chrome extension (message from background to other js) : Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Since background.js is a service worker, I can't use DOM function or localstorage. I'm trying to find a way around by using messages to execute JS outside background.js but with simple message passing, I get the error message: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

In background.js I have:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ data: [action] }, function (response) 
    {
        console.log('sending message');
    });
```

In popup.js I have:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, reply) => 
{
    console.log('message received');
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

1. Update translations, error messages, ... once a day. In that case I create an alarm in background.js that downloads JSON containing the metadata but I then need to store it locally but that doesn't work with background.js
2. Create a tab, download the source code and parse it. I could do this in background.js in manifest v2 but I had to move those functions to popup.js but that's annoying because popup.js can easily be interrupted.

How could I use background.js to create recurring tasks in the background and send some content to other scripts to compensate for what background.js cannot do? I guess popup.js is not always active or always listening, that's probably why I get this error message.

I thought of using this:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript( 
{
target: {tabId: tab.id, allFrames: true},
files: ['myscript.js'],
}
```

but I need a target that I don't have for my use cases.

thanks

Comment: Indeed, the popup runs only when shown so it can't receive messages when hidden.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, that makes sense. Is there an alternative?

Comment: No. ManifestV3 is still only half-usable. See also https://crbug.com/1056354.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok, I thought it was already a stable/final version. Maybe I should go back to Manifest v2. Do you know until when v2 will be accepted?